# Hash and sha256 - Objective-c and Java. Return wrong

Tags: java, objective-c, hash, sha, sha256

Why am i getting another hash? ObjC returns wrong hash. Why?

**Objective-c:**

```
NSString *key = @"rain";
NSString *data = @"http://google.com";
const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
NSString *hash = [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"%@", hash);
```

`hash: J6PCNtA36h/6OdxdmKRFr0mLN3GgFQWAji2ciuTkmhE=`

**Java:**

```
public class HelloWorld{

   public static String encode(String key, String data) throws Exception {
    Base64.Decoder decoder= Base64.getDecoder();
    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(decoder.decode(key), "HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
    byte[] mac_data = sha256_HMAC.doFinal(data.getBytes());
    Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
    return encoder.encodeToString(mac_data);
}

 public static void main(String []args){
     try{
    System.out.println(encode("rain", "http://google.com"));
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {

     }
 }
}
```

`hash: Ua2G90mCKIlx2WF2U5VsOkZcEn6GzfONa4pL0waCLnY=`

Help me please.

Comment: this doesn't solve your problem, but I think that since you are passing your key in text plain (not B64), you can pass key.getBytes("UTF-8") to the SecretKeySpec constructor (instead of decoder.decode(key)), but still produces same output as yours